# Using jquery with EditItemTemplate of Datalist control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datalist, edititemtemplate

Is it possible to access controls inside EditItemTemplate of Datalist control using jquery. I have difficult time doing it, because "Edit" row is not rendered in html.

The only alternative I thanked of is not using DataList EditItemTemplate, but rather go only with jquery to hide and show rows and use ajax to update the contents of a row.

But, I would still want to hear option for EditItemTemplate and jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the html **is** rendered but only when you click on [Edit]
see this post it shoud help you http://forums.asp.net/t/1668230.aspx/1

try this:
javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {         
        showID();
    });

    function showID() {         
        if ($("[id*=QtyTextBox]").length)
            alert($("[id*=QtyTextBox]").attr("id"));
    }
</script>
```

EditItemTemplate:

```
<EditItemTemplate>              
            Quantity:
            <asp:TextBox ID="QtyTextBox" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Qty") %>'
                runat="server" />
            <br />              
            <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"
                runat="server" />               
        </EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I followed your solution, but there is a problem. Please see my code below.

Comment: <EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" Width=80% Runat="server" 
Text='<%# Bind("startdate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat=server ID="rfvStartDate" ControlToValidate="txtStartDate" ErrorMessage="!"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RangeValidator runat=server ID="rvStartDate" ControlToValidate="txtStartDate" ErrorMessage="!" Type=Date MinimumValue="01.01.2000" MaximumValue="01.01.2050"></asp:RangeValidator>

</EditItemTemplate>

Comment: Funny thing is getting a value is not a problem. I get value for $(this).val(), but I am not able to get the ID of the control. I tried everything...

Comment: Yes, I didn't think of getting the id with attrib. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your solution, but there is a problem. Now I am able to trigger an event, but the following code returns id as "undefined", despite the fact that it is declared inside datalist.

```
function bindPicker() {
            $("input[type=text][id*=txtStartDate]").click(
            function()
            {
                alert($(this).id);
            });
        }
```

I am not sure how to reference controls that triggered an event.